# Muli font is not rendering properly

Tags: html, css, fonts, wkhtmltopdf

I have problem with proper font rendering in html and `wkhtmltopdf`. I am using `Muli` font in the whole body (download from Google: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Muli), but some parts are cut out (image below where zeros are not well rounded). I do not see the same effect with `Roboto` or `Montserrat`. Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
      }
      .thin {
        font-weight: 200;
      }
      .light {
        font-weight: 300;
      }
      .regular {
        font-weight: 400;
      }
      .bold {
        font-weight: 600;
      }
      .extraBold {
        font-weight: 700;
      }
      .black {
        font-weight: 800;
      }
      .extraBlack {
        font-weight: 900;
      }
   </style>
  </head>
```

`wkhtmltopdf -L 0 -R 0 -T 0 -B 0 --page-width 2933px --page-height 5194px --disable-smart-shrinking`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap');
        body {
            font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 110px;
            font-weight: 900;
            color: #00b3b8;
        }
        h2 {
            font-size: 110px;
            font-weight: 700;
            color: #001fb8;
        }
        h3 {
            font-size: 110px;
            font-weight: 600;
            color: #b88800;
        }
        h4 {
            font-size: 110px;
            font-weight: 400;
            color: #b82a00;
        }
        h5 {
            font-size: 110px;
            font-weight: 300;
            color: #ad00b8;
        }
        h6 {
            font-size: 110px;
            font-weight: 200;
            color: #000000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>100</h1>
    <h2>200</h2>
    <h3>300</h3>
    <h4>400</h4>
    <h5>500</h5>
    <h6>600</h6>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that could be causing issues. Or possibly a combination of serveral.

1. Make sure you're specifying font sizes in `pt` or `em` NOT `px`. The reason for this is `kerning tables` (usually built into the font) combine with font-smoothing and converting pixel to print sizes can cause artifacts.
2. In the past I've experienced the Google Font downloaded to my computer was physically different than what is streamed via javascript from the service. I assume they don't get updated at the same time. If you can try letting Google's server provide the font each time. Or can you try finding the files elsewhere? (this sounds like a corrupted font file)
3. If you are self-hosting the fonts, make sure that your server is sending them with the correct MIME type. Here's a [list](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#font) of what they should be. You can change that in IIS or your `.htaccess` file depending on the server environment you have. *I know this seems strange since it's only one font, but the other's you've tried could be loading a different font type (ttf, otf, etc) that what the browser is getting for Muli*

---

If none of that helps could you post more of you're CSS including how the fonts are loaded and how they're set to display (size, smoothing, line-height, etc)?

Comment: thanks for answer. I am using px to specify the font size, so maybe I will start from there. I am using Linux and so far I managed to get decent look with Roboto font that was preinstalled on my system.

Comment: Just remember you can't count on roboto being installed on most systems...